# Connecting to a MySQL database via php in bluehost

Tags: mysql, bluehost

Hi  Im having a MYSQL database on bluehost and I'm trying to connect to it using PHP. The PHP files that are used are stored in the public_html under my domain.  Given below are the two codes

db_config.php

```
<?php

/*
* All database connection variables
*/

define('DB_USER', "siveradi_root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "Tesh123"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "siveradi_test"); // database name
define('DB_HOST', "localhost:3306"); // db server
define('DB_PORT',"3306");
?>
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php

/**
* A class file to connect to database
*/
class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . 'http://mangominds.info/test_mera/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

However when I try to connect the database through

```
<?php
$db = new DB_CONNECT(); // creating class object(will open database connection)

?>
```

an error is shown saying "server error The website encountered an error while retrieving http://mangominds.info/test_mera/tt.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

PLease advice on what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you remove the port from `define('DB_HOST', "localhost:3306"); // db server`

and make it:

```
define('DB_HOST', "localhost"); // db server
```

Also try not to comment the last line with the port number and leave only the DB_HOST definition without the port